# Disable frontend Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

We would like to disable the magento 1 frontend to the public.

The magento application is only availible for the suppliers and as an inventory management tool.

The data feeds need to be accessed.

How do I disable only the frontend?

Answer (score 2):

Also look into applying blank theme as frontend theme and blank cms page for homepage.

So even if client has access by IP as demonstrated in other answer they can't go clicking around an unmanaged frontend

Comment: Hello, When i enable the blank theme there is still some magento stuff on the frontend, do you know how i can dusable this? https://imgur.com/wVrf2Qo

Comment: @WouterStulp I know how to do it in Magento 2.  You create a new page layout in xml https://github.com/DominicWatts/Lightweight404/blob/master/view/frontend/layout/page_not_found.xml similar approach in M1 - just syntax would be different

Answer (score 1):

you can modify index.php file here added maintenance.flag and IP condition in that variable $allowed

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('192.168.0.1','2.2.2.2');

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

hope this will be helpful to you

Comment: Hello, This answer will not work because we cant access the backend of the magento installation. we dont want to manually add ip addresses because this can change.